# Delete confirm only using PHP

Tags: php

I want to delete links to delete images on an SQL database. I am tasked with creating a delete confirm option not using JavaScript just PHP.

```
require_once("photoalbum-common.php");

$pdo = connect();

if ( isset( $_GET['deletionid'])) {
  $errorMessage = deletePhotograph( $pdo, $_GET['deletionid']);
  if ( $errorMessage != "") {
    print "<div class='errormessage'>$errorMessage</div>\n";
  } else {
    print "<div class='message'>Image deleted.</div>\n";    
  }
}
```

The code below is in "photoalbum-common.php".

```
<?php

function deletePhotograph( $pdo, $deletionid) {
  $errorMessage = "";
  // retrieve name of image file so we can delete it
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `image` FROM `photographs` WHERE `photoid`=?");
  $stmt->execute( array( $deletionid));  
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if ( count( $rows) == 1) {
    // delete file
    unlink( "images/".$rows[0]['image']);    
    // delete database record
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `photographs` WHERE `photoid`=?");
    $stmt->execute( array( $deletionid));  
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();    
  } else if (count( $rows) > 1) {
    $errorMessage .= "ID matches more than one record. ";
  } else {
    $errorMessage .= "ID not found: nothing to delete. ";
  }
  return $errorMessage;
}

?>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I need a delete confirm, so when delete is clicked it asks the user whether they want to delete it "yes" or "no".

Comment: If you can't use Javascript and AJAX, you'll have to take the user to a second URL or reload the page to display new options.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this. An interstitial page, that accepts a GET request:

**GET Request** `GET /delete.php?id=123`

> Are you sure you wanna delete?

**POST Request** `POST /delete.php?id=123`

> Execute the PDO.

You are supposed to write the code for the PHP. If the answer is not enough for this, well, here we go:

```
<?php
  if (count($_POST)) {
    // POST Request
    deletePhotograph();
  } else {
    // GET Request
    ?>
    <p>Are you sure you wanna delete?</p>
    <!-- Empty action will POST to the same page. -->
    <form action="" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="I confirm, Delete" /></form>
    <?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pav i'll give it a go.